# Error while parsing JSON Array

Tags: android, arrays, json, parsing

I've got this JSON data to parse into my Android application :

```
{"result":"success","source":"getPlayerNames","success":["Player1","Player2"]}
```

To parse it, I'm doing this way (where `jsonData` is a String containing the above data) :

```
ArrayList<String> players;
players = new ArrayList();

JSONObject json = new JSONObject(jsonData);
JSONArray array = json.getJSONArray("success");

for (int i = 0; i < array.length() ; i++)
{
    players.add(array.getString(i));
}
```

But the `players` ArrayList is still empty... (size = 0)

Why ? Could you help me ?

Thanks !

Comment: Your code works just fine, I've tested it myself. There is no problem here.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change this

```
players = new ArrayList();
```

to :

```
players = new ArrayList<String>();
```

See if  it helps

**EDIT:**
Got it. Working code:

```
ArrayList<String> players;
players = new ArrayList();

JSONObject json = new JSONObject(jsonData);
JSONArray array = json.getJSONArray("success");

for (int i = 0; i < array.length() ; i++)
{
    players.add((String)array.get(i));
}
```

Comment: Nope, still the same... I think the problem is in the JSONArray parsing, but where ?

Comment: The generics declaration and cast to a String are implicit so change nothing. I would actually strongly favor @user1947177's use of `getString` over a `get` as it allows `org.json` to do some error checking for you.